# MySQL Workbench 6.0 ce will not start on Windows 8 Pro

Tags: windows-8, mysql, mysql-workbench

Just install windows 8 Pro

Install xampp for mysql and php

while install mysql workbench 6.0

Install went fine but the application does not start

Try to install the version of mysql workbench 5.0

Still the same problem.

Tried the zip version still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several hours of search i noted that

You should check for the following

To be able to run MySQL Workbench 5.2 your System needs to have libraries listed below installed.

- Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package
- OpenGL

Note that even though windows 8 comme with preinstall Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package and Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile

You should make sure you have the 32-bit version of these application.

Comment: worked perfectly for me, although OpenGL wasn't required.